# React router: component not rendering after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, webpack, react-router

I'm building a website using React and I'm trying to redirect the user to the index page after the login, but my component is not rendering anything, although I'm being redirected and I can see the URL changing from */welcome#/login* to */main*. 
Since I'm not getting any error messages and the webpack is being successfully compiled, I can't see what's wrong anymore. 
Any ideas of what could possibly be wrong?

Thank you very much!

**Start.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Welcome from "./welcome";
import { App } from "./app";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import reduxPromise from "redux-promise";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import reducer from "./reducer";

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(reduxPromise))
);

let element;

if (location.pathname === "/welcome") {
    element = <Welcome />;
} else {
    init(store);
    element = (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(element, document.querySelector("main"));
```

**Welcome.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Register from "./register";
import Login from "./login";
import { HashRouter, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export default class Welcome extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <HashRouter>
                <div className="register-wrapper">
                    <div>
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Register} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </HashRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

**Login Component**

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "./axios";

export default class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.state = { error: false };
        this.loginButton = this.loginButton.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    loginButton(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios
            .post("/login", this.state)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.data.success) {
                    location.replace("/main");
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        error: true
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    handleChange(e) {

        this.setState(
            {
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            },
            () => console.log("this.state:", this.state)
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="login-main-container">

                {this.state.error && <h2>Ops! Something went wrong.</h2>}

                <h1 className="login-title">Kathi & Rodolfo</h1>
                <h2 className="login-subtitle">Dear guest, please login first</h2>

                <div className="login-container">
                    <form className="login-form">
                        <label className="label-login" htmlFor="email"> username </label>
                        <input className="input-login"

                            name="email"
                            placeholder="Best Couple You Know"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                        <label className="label-login" htmlFor="password"> password </label>
                        <input className="input-login"
                            name="password"
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="Super Loving Password"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />

                        <button
                            className="login-button"
                            onClick={this.loginButton}
                        >
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <h4 className="login-info">Information about username and password can be found on the Save The Date card</h4>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Index Component (Main)**

```
import React from "react";

export default class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state ={ error: false};
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className="main-container"> 
                <header>
                    <p>the wedding</p>
                    <p>rpsv</p>
                    <p>contact us</p>
                    <p>wedding gift</p>
                </header>

                {this.state.error && <h2>Ops! Something went wrong.</h2>}

                <div className="save-the-date-img">
                    <h1>Save The Date</h1>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from "./main";

export class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/main" Component={Main}/>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're using the `Login` component anywhere... (in Main or App)

Comment: I am! I will add this block of code to my actual question. Could be the issue is there, indeed. Good call!

Comment: Your issue is definitely stemming from using two routers `HashRouter` and `BrowserRouter` - which doesn't make any sense. You're also mounting the hash router on the `/welcome` route, which explains your trouble escaping that. My suggestions: try to fold all that routing logic into one router (I don't much care which but I prefer `BrowserRouter`) AND do your best to stay away from Redux until you're sure that you need it (as in you have a problem keeping track of state) - because as it stands you probably don't.

Answer (score 1):

`location.replace("/main");`
I think this line is wrong in your code.

While you are using React, you'd rather use react-router-dom's functionality than browser built-in feature. 
Change the line to `this.props.history.push('/main')`

Comment: Yeah, I thought that would be the issue, too. I've changed this line before and the only thing that happens is that the URL changes to *welcome#/main* instead of */main*. Maybe the problem is on another block of code/component. Thank you very much!

Comment: @LuisaSilva Did you try this.props.history.push('../main')

Comment: Yup! I've tried this.props.history.push('../main'), this.props.history.push('./main') and this.props.history.push('/main') without success.

Answer (score 0):

Give your file structure. Your component `Login` is not in `BrowserRouter`, but must be. Check the official sample: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start.

Comment: Hey! It's in, actually. I just updated my issue so it's a little bit more clear. Thanks for the link, though. I'll definitely have a look!

Comment: You don't need to set location.pathname. Add Switch to your project.

Comment: Thanks for your tip! Would you mind explaining why that would be better?

Comment: Just read the docs I have given above and your life will become more easy:) Switch component is valid. React-router-dom already has history middleware so it pushes location's pathname automatically up on Route's prop `path`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
location.replace("/main");
```

use

```
history.push("/main")
```